# Parsing text by regex, split, tokinize, or hash

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

I am parsing a CSV file that contains text that represents duration, which might be any combination of hours, minutes, or both. For example:

1. "1 hour 30 minutes"
2. "2 hours"
3. "45 minutes"

I want to be able to do this: `duration = h.hours + m.minutes` and make sure that `h` is hour (if exists) and the same for `m`.

I tried solving this with this regex `/(\d*)\s?hour\D*(\d*)\s?min/)` , but this won't detect minutes alone, or hours alone.

So I changed it to this `/(\d+)\s?\D*\s?(\d*)/`, but it's wrong too because there is no way to tell if the value is an hour or minute, so I can convert it to `hour` or `minutes`.

I am confused on which way could solve this problem in my app. Is it regex, hash, matching, or any other way? Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: What exact output do you want to generate with those inputs?

Comment: i want to convert to seconds, so for example 
`duration = h.hours + m.minutes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward to match with regex if you know that there is at least one of those present in the string. For example:

```
(?:(\d+)\s*hours?)?\s*(?:(\d+)\s*minutes?)?
```

Comment: yes, but how would i tell which is minutes and which is hours ? so i know how to convert correctly ? something like :
`duration = h.hours + m.minutes`

Comment: @Mawaheb, hours would always be in the first capturing group, minutes always in the second.

Comment: results in parenthesis are captured into `$1` -> `$9`

Comment: @Qtax can you please try to explain your reg-ex? that would really help me to understand it well and understand how it works..Thanks in advance

Comment: @Qtax that is really a good site! I've been using http://rubular.com/
but I think from now on, I will use the one you suggested! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one fancy way:

```
def string_to_duration(string)
  string.downcase.scan(/(\d+)\s+(hours?|minutes?)/).map do |number, unit|
    number.to_i.send(unit)
  end.reduce(:+)
end
```

Test:

```
require "active_support/all"

input = [
  "1 hour 30 minutes",
  "2 hours",
  "45 minutes"
]

def string_to_duration(string)
  string.downcase.scan(/(\d+)\s+(hours?|minutes?)/).map do |number, unit|
    number.to_i.send(unit)
  end.reduce(:+)
end

input.each do |str|
  puts string_to_duration str
end
```

Output:

```
5400
7200
2700
```

Note: This would also accept duplicate units like `"1 minute 1 minute 1 minute"` will print `180`.

Comment: I don't know any ruby, but I'm curious, how does this work? What multiplies the number to the right amount of seconds? What does `.send(unit)` do?

Comment: @Qtax, from your profile, I see you _do_ know JS, so `a.send(unit)` == `a[unit]()`. Let me know if that explains it!

Comment: @Qtax `Numeric#hours` and `Numeric#minutes` are helper method introduced by ActiveSupport in Rails, which calculates the numeric hours/minutes to seconds. `a.send('hours')` is the same as `a.hours`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do and I believe it's the most straightforward way:

```
str = "1 hour 30 minutes"
h = str[/(\d+) hour/, 1].to_i rescue 0
m = str[/(\d+) minute/, 1].to_i rescue 0
```